# Plugin to handle selection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Can anyone suggest a plugin which can handle text selections in text areas (cross browser)?

I'm looking for a plugin which can:

- Get current selection
- Replace current selection
- Select a range

(IE uses `createTextRange` while other browsers use `setSelectionRange`. There ought to exist an plugin which can do the above so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.)

Comment: Perhaps you can be a bit more specific about the features you would imagine such a plugin would have?

Comment: Not a plugin exactly, but take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/985272/552438).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**jQuery Fieldselection:**
https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection

See:
https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection/blob/master/jquery-fieldselection.js

*Implements:* getSelection, replaceSelection

*Does not implement:* currentSelection

**Rangy:**
*Implements:* getSelection, ReplaceSelection, CurrentSelection

(note: not a jquery plugin, but widely applicable still)

> A cross-browser JavaScript range and selection library. It provides a simple standards-based API for performing common DOM Range and Selection tasks in all major browsers, abstracting away the wildly different implementations of this functionality between Internet Explorer and DOM-compliant browsers.

Seems to implement what you want, for demo's see:
http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/core.html

http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

See also: [Jquery: selectionStart for non textarea elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453841/jquery-selectionstart-for-non-textarea-elements)

**Rangyinputs**
A jquery plugin that offers similar functionality as Rangy, except for inputs instead of arbitrairy DOM elements.

> A small cross-browser JavaScript library for obtaining and manipulating selections within  and  HTML elements.

Demo: http://rangyinputs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textinputs_jquery.html

Project: http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/

Answer (score 0):

Below plugin may help you http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php

It was helpful too me

Answer (score 0):

I created my own. Only 2.6kb uncompressed: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/a-javascript-selection-script/

```
//jQuery is not required but supported.
var selection = new textSelector($('#mytextarea'));
selection.replace('New text');

// you can change selection:
selection.select(1,10); // select char 1 to 10

// get selection
console.log("Start char: " + selection.get().start);

// check if anything is selected
selection.isSelected();

// get the text
var text = selection.text();
```

It's available at github: https://raw.github.com/jgauffin/griffin.editor/master/Source/textselector.js

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the links present here, and others from the jQuery plugin repository, and none of them worked the way I wanted.

But there is this one, not mentionned here, that is really interesting :

http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/

Hope it'll helps ! :)

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/mattsich/pen/MKvmxQ for an iOS style selection I built. Ends up being just this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".full-text").selectBars('.full-text', 'ipsum', function(){
    $('.selected-text p').text($('.full-text').attr('data-selected'));
  });

});
```